# How user adds values on dictionary; Method returns expected value and none

Tags: python, class, methods, dictionary

I have two questions.

1 - How user adds values on a dictionary? All exemples about dict's that I seen, they are already predefined by the programmer.

2 - I wrote this class

```
class Imovel:                                       
    tamanho = 0                                     
    cor = ''

    def __init__(self, tamanho, cor):               
        self.tamanho = tamanho
        self.cor = cor

    def verificarDisponibilidade(self, situacao):   
        self.situacao = situacao
        if(situacao == True):
            print 'Imovel disponivel'
        else:
            print 'Imovel indisponivel'
```

When I call verificarDisponibilidade() and pass True as parameter, I expect "*Imovel disponivel*" but I got:

```
Imovel disponivel
None
```

I wonder what that "None" is returned.

Thanks all, and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Your probably calling `print instance.verificarDisponibilidade(True)`, which causes the string you expect to be printed, then the result of the function (which is None) to also be printed

Comment: Also, when checking is something is True, don't compare it to True - that's what if does. just use `if self.situacao:`

Comment: At first I put `If situacao:`, but I thought it might cause some error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding values to a dictionary is easy:

```
d={}
d['somekey']=somevalue
```

Or you can do it during dictionary creation:

```
d={'some_key':some_value,'some_other_key':some_other_value}
```

Or, you can add one dictionary into another one:

```
d1={}
d2={'foo':'bar'}
d1.update(d2)
```

As far as your function returning, all python functions return `None` unless told otherwise by a `return` statement:

```
def foo():
   #prints to the screen and returns None
   print "Hi"

def bar():
   #prints to the screen and returns "Hi"
   print "Hi"
   return "Hi"
```

On an unrelated note, it is best to have your class inherit from `object`.

```
class Imovel(object):
    ...
```

That makes it a new-style class which are generally better than old style classes.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I want to know if have as the end-user to add, not the programmer. For example: The user enters random values ​​10 and they are added in a dictionary.

Comment: @crf_h0m3r -- If the user enters the value 10, what do you want to use for a key?  You could do `d['user_input']=raw_input()` or something to that effect, is that what you mean?

Comment: In the case of several averages of several students, the end-user add the name of the student and the average of it and that would be stored in a dictionary. The student's name as key and as the average as value. (This is an example)

Comment: Something like this should work (assuming the user puts the information in correctly):  `name,average=raw_input("enter Name,Average").split(',')` and then: `d[name.strip()]=float(average)`.

Comment: Thank you @mgilson! I tested here and and I think it worked, when I print d, result: `{u'filipe': 9.8}`, but this is unicode, right? But when I print `d['name', 'average']` after putting the values, I got: `KeyError ('name', 'values')`

Comment: @crf_h0m3r: I would advise you to read the python [documentation on dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the printed output, then the return value of that function. Since you have no `return` statement, `None` is implicitly returned. And that's what you see.

Try, and compare:

```
def verificarDisponibilidade(self, situacao):   
    self.situacao = situacao
    if(situacao == True):
        return 'Imovel disponivel'
    else:
        return 'Imovel indisponivel'
```